If $\overline{\varphi}: M/IM\to N/IN$ is surjective, when is $\varphi: M \to N$ surjective?
Let's consider the following statement $\text{P(A, B)}$ depending on some parameters $\text{(A)}$ and $\text{(B)}$:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $I \subseteq R$ an ideal and $M$, $N$ $R$-modules. Assume furthermore that $I$ fulfills condition $\text{(A)}$ and $N$ fulfills condition $\text{(B)}$. If $\varphi: M \to N$ is a module homomorphism such that the induced homomorphism $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \overline{\varphi}: \quotient{M}{IM} \to \quotient{N}{IN}$ is surjective, then $\varphi$ is surjective.

I want to allow the following the following properties as the parameter $\text{(A)}$:

$\text{(A1)}$ $I$ is nilpotent, i.e. there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $I^n = \{0\}$

$\text{(A2)}$ $I$ consists only of nilpotent elements. The following conditions are equivalent to this one: (1.) $I$ is contained in the nilradical (2.) $I$ is contained in every prime ideal

$\text{(A3)}$ $I$ is contained in the Jacobson radical. The following conditions are equivalent to this one: (1.) $I$ is contained in every maximal ideal (2.) For every $a \in I$ and $b \in R$, $1 + ab$ is invertible.


It is clear that $\text{(A1)} \Rightarrow \text{(A2)} \Rightarrow \text{(A3)}$.
I want to allow the following properties as the parameter $\text{(B)}$:

$\text{(B1)}$ $N$ is finitely generated

$\text{(B2)}$ No condition.


Of course $\text{(B1)} \Rightarrow \text{(B2)}$.
I would like to know whether the statement $\text{P(A, B)}$ is correct for all possible tuples $(\text{A}, \text{B}) \in \{\text{A1}, \text{A2}, \text{A3}\} \times \{\text{B1}, \text{B2}\}$.

The case $(\text{A1}, \text{B2})$ was asked in the following question: $\overline\phi: M/IM \to N/IN$ is surjective, then $\phi$ is surjective. . In this case, $\text{P(A1, B2)}$ is true and the argument goes as follows: $\overline{\varphi}: \quotient{M}{IM} \to \quotient{N}{IN}$ is surjective iff $\pi_N \circ \varphi: M \to \quotient{N}{IN}$ is surjective. This can be expressed as $\pi(\varphi(M)) = \quotient{N}{IN}$ or equivalently $\varphi(M) + IN = N$. Next, we have $N = \varphi(M) + IN = \varphi(M) + I(\varphi(M) + IN) = \varphi(M) + I^2 N$. Inductively, we obtain $N = \varphi(M) + I^k N$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, we have $N = \varphi(M) + I^n N = \varphi(M) + \{0\} N = \varphi(M)$. Hence $\varphi$ is surjective. Hence $\text{P(A1, B2)}$ is true. Since $\text{(B1)} \Rightarrow \text{(B2)}$, this also shows that $\text{P(A1, B1)}$ is true.

The case $(\text{A3}, \text{B1})$ was a homework problem in my Algebra I class. It is also the topic of the following questions: Prove that if the induced homomorphism $M/\mathfrak aM \to N/\mathfrak aN$ is surjective, then $f$ it's surjective. & Exercise using Nakayama Lemma . In this case, $\text{P(A3, B1)}$ is true. I gave the following answer: $\overline{\varphi}: \quotient{M}{IM} \to \quotient{N}{IN}$ is surjective iff $\pi_N \circ \varphi: M \to \quotient{N}{IN}$ is surjective. This can be expressed as $\pi(\varphi(M)) = \quotient{N}{IN}$ or equivalently $\varphi(M) + IN = N$. But now $M$ is finitely generated and $I$ is contained in the Jacobson radical. A version of Nakayama's Lemma now implies that $\varphi(M) = N$, i.e. that $\varphi$ is surjective. This shows that $\text{P(A3, B1)}$ is true. Since $\text{(A1)} \Rightarrow \text{(A2)} \Rightarrow \text{(A3)}$, this also shows that $\text{P(A2, B1)}$ is true and that $\text{P(A1, B1)}$ is true.

The case $(\text{A3}, \text{B2})$ admits a counterexample. My counterexample is based on the following answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/649958/491450 . It is also presented here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416504/491450 . Take $R = \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, which is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $I = p \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. Let $M = \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and $N = \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\iota: \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is clearly not surjective, but $\overline{\iota}: \mathbb{F}_p \to 0$ is surjective. Hence $\text{P(A3, B2)}$ is false.


We now have the following table:



$\text{P(A, B)}$
$\text{(A1)}$
$\text{(A2)}$
$\text{(A3)}$




$\text{(B1)}$
true
true
true


$\text{(B2)}$
true
?
false



Question: What about $\text{P(A2, B2)}$?

In general, you can assume $M=0$ (why?), so your question is really when $N=I \cdot N$ implies $N=0$.

@MartinBrandenburg Presumably taking cokernels commutes with taking the quotient by $I$, so that $\varphi$ surjective $\Leftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{coker}(\varphi) = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{coker}(\varphi) = I\operatorname{coker}(\varphi)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \quotient{\operatorname{coker}(\varphi)}{I\operatorname{coker}(\varphi)} = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{coker}(\overline{\varphi}) = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\overline{\varphi}$ surjective.

By considering the cokernel of $\varphi$ one can reduce to the case $M=0$. So it's really about when $N=IN$ implies $N=0$.
Q1. Let $$R := K[X_1, X_2, X_3, \dotsc] / (X_1^2, X_n - X_{n+1}^2 : n \geq 0)$$ and $I = (X_1,X_2,\dotsc)$. Then $I$ is a nil ideal with $I = I^2$ (clear) but $I \neq 0$ (requires a proof).

Is it really nonzero? We have $X_n = X_{n + 1}X_{n+2} = X_{n+2}X_{n+3}X_{n+2} = {X_{n+2}}^2X_{n+3} = 0$.

I think we should take $$R := K[X_1, X_2, X_3, \dotsc] / (X_1^2, X_n - {X_{n+1}}^2: n \geq 0)$$

Yes, I fixed it.

Regarding Q2 I suggest to ask a separate question. It is always good to focus on just one question per post (unless they are closely related). This is also required by the site guidelines. Otherwise it also makes it hard to accept just one answer.

Without restrictions on $N$, the relevant property here is really $T$-nilpotence, where $T$ stands for transfinite.

The following are equivalent for an ideal $I \subseteq R$:
(1) For any sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ of elements contained in $I$, there exists $n$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = 0$.
(2) For any sequence $(I_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ of finitely generated ideals contained in $I$, there exists $n$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^n I_i =0$.
(3) For every $R$-module $N$, $N= IN$ implies $N = 0$.
(4) For every homomorphism of $R$-modules $M \rightarrow N$, surjectivity of $M/IM \rightarrow N/IM$ implies surjectivity of $M \rightarrow N$.

Proof:
$(1) \implies (2)$ This is just König's infinity lemma.  A fun application of basic graph theory to algebra.
$(2) \implies (3)$   Pick any $y_0 \in N$.  Since $N \subseteq IN$, find a finitely generated ideal $I_1 \subseteq I$ such that $y_0 \in I_0N$, $y_0 = \sum a_{1i}y_{1i}$ with $a_{1i} \in I_1$.  At the next stage, find a finitely generated ideal $I_2 \subseteq I$ such that every $y_{1i} \subseteq I_2$.  Then by construction $y_0 \in I_1 I_2 N$.  Continuing on indefinitely in this manner, we construct a sequence of finitely generated ideals $I_i$ contained $I$ such that $y_0 \in (\prod_{i=1}^n I_i) N$ for any $n$.  By assumption, one of these products vanishes, so $y_0 = 0$.
$(3) \implies (1)$ Let $(a_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of elements contained in $I$.  Consider the sequence of module maps $R \xrightarrow{a_1} R \xrightarrow{a_2} R \xrightarrow{a_3} R \cdots$ defined by multiplication by the corresponding $a_i$. Let $N$ be the colimit of this system.  It is immediate that $N = IN$.  By our assumption in $(3)$, $N = 0$.  In particular, the element $1 \in R$ at the first stage of the system must map to $0$ in the $n$th stage for $n$, which means precisely that $\prod_{i=1}^n{a_i} = 0$.
$(3) \implies (4)$ (This is merely an expansion of Martin Brandenburg's comment about cokernels).  Suppose that $M/IM \rightarrow N/IN$ is surjective. In other words, $M \rightarrow N$ becomes surjective after being tensored with $R/I$.  Let $Q$ be the cokernel of $M \rightarrow N$.  Since cokernels commute with tensor product (a consequence of the tensor product being right exact), we find that $Q/IQ = 0$.  Therefore $Q = 0$ by $(3)$, and $M \rightarrow N$ is already surjective.
$(4) \implies (3)$ Evaluate the statement of $(4)$ with $M = 0$.
